# Gradle project not found in root project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle project that has the following format:

```
DerivedProject
        settings.gradle
        build.gradle
        DerivedFolderA
        DerivedFolderB
```

Both DerivedFolderA and DerivedFolderB just contain java code, no gradle or settings.gradle files.
DerivedProject build.gradle has the following tasks:

```
project(':DerivedFolderA')
project(':DerivedFolderB')
```

DerivedProject settings.gradle has the following definition:

```
rootProject.name = 'DerivedProject'
include 'DerivedFolderA', 'DerivedFolderB'
```

I can build this project just fine.

I am trying to add this code to a root package that looks like the following:

```
RootPackage
    settings.gradle
    build.gradle
    SubdirectoryA
        build.gradle
    SubdirectoryB
        build.gradle
    SubdirectoryC
        DerivedProject
            settings.gradle
            build.gradle
            DerivedFolderA
            DerivedFolderB
```

settings.gradle in the root project has the following:

```
include 'SubdirectoryA', \
include 'SubdirectoryB', \
include 'SubdirectoryC:DerivedProject'
```

However, when I run gradle build from the RootPackage, I get an error:

```
* Where:
Build file '/RootProject/SubdirectoryC/DerivedProject/build.gradle' line: 118

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':SubdirectoryC:DerivedProject'.
> Project with path ':DerivedFolderA' could not be found in project ':SubdirectoryC:DerivedProject'.
```

I thought just sourcing the DerivedProject in the root directory would be enough.  Is there something I am missing in my gradle definitions?

Comment: Could you show "DerivedProject/build.gradle' line: 118" ?

Comment: DerivedProjects/build.gradle looks like the following:  project(':DerivedFolderA')

Comment: You may not have a multi-project build as part of another multi-project build. Only the root project must have a settings.gradle file.

Comment: @JBNizet . Thank you, that worked.

Comment: I have the same error using a composite project. just fyi .  in that case i do have settings.gradle files in each sub-module (so each sub-module can declare its own root).    That being the case, I still have this question asked by the author.